# Tables creation errorCannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1064

I am facing problems on creating foreign key. Below are my query:

```
CREATE TABLE supervisee
(
  supervisee_staff_id           VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  supervisee_email_address      VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  supervisee_name           VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(supervisee_staff_id),
  FOREIGN KEY(academic_id) 
  REFERENCES academic_result(academic_result_id)
)

CREATE TABLE academic_result
(
  academic_result_id        INTEGER(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(academic_result_id)
)
```

any help from you would be grateful, thanks alot! :)

Comment: Did you manage to sort your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what error you are receiving, but I see two potential problems. Your foreign key column academic_id needs to be defined as its own column as well as being in the FOREIGN KEY clause. Secondly, define the dependent (academic_result) table first so that when you define the foreign key, it has something to refer to. Try this for example:

```
CREATE TABLE academic_result ( 
  academic_result_id INTEGER(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(academic_result_id) 
);
CREATE TABLE supervisee ( 
  supervisee_staff_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
  supervisee_email_address VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
  supervisee_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
  academic_id INTEGER(6),
  PRIMARY KEY(supervisee_staff_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(academic_id) 
    REFERENCES academic_result(academic_result_id) 
);
```